# Flex 3 - Dynamic columns DataGrid, ItemRenderer, TextInput, how to set the property "text"?

Tags: dynamic, datagrid, flex3

Here is the case (Flex 3):
I have a,

- DataGrid with dynamic number of columns;
- Each cell as a ItemRender;
- Each ItemRenderer as a TextInput;

If the number of columns stayed equal then the property text of the textInput in the item render, would be `<mx:textInput id="ti" text="{data.ColumName}"/>`.
But i have a dynamic number of columnName!
Therefore i can´t acess `text="{data."diferent columName"}"` !
 Any help??

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've found the correct way to access the diferent columns names, in order to acess the dataprovider!
The Itemrender mxml:

```
<mx:TextInput width="100%" height="100%" click="cellClickHandler(event)" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
<mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridListData;
            import mx.controls.listClasses.ListData;

            override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                if(value != null)
                {
                    super.data = value;
                    var dglistData:DataGridListData = listData as DataGridListData;
                    this.text = value[dglistData.dataField];
                }
            } 

            public function cellClickHandler(e:Event)
            {

            }
    ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:TextInput>
```